# C++ code crashes and has an infinite loop

Tags: c++, linked-list, crash, queue, infinite-loop

I have  several problems with this code;

***First***, if I run it then I chose **PUSH** and typed two names like "Emily Glassberg" it goes into **infinite loop** but if I typed only one name like "Michael" it works good.[Problem picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9sbK.png)

**Secondly**, after I run the code when I

1. choose **"PUSH"** -type one name-
2. then  choose **"Delete"**
3. then choose **"PUSH"** -and type one name again- the program **crashes**,
   It even **crashes** if I chose **"Delete"** only before I enter any names.
   [Problem 2.1 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCZh1.png) 
   [Problem 2.2 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvkEE.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct Queue
{
    struct node
    {
        node *next;
        string name;
    };

    node *head;
    int front=-1,rare=-1;

    void push(string x)
    {
        if (rare < 0 )
        {
            head =new node;
            head->next=NULL;
            head->name=x;
            rare ++;
        }
        else
        {
            node *temp,*temp1;
            temp=head;

            while(temp->next != NULL){temp=temp->next;}

            temp1=new node;
            temp->next=temp1;
            temp1->next=NULL;
            temp1->name=x;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        node *temp;
        temp=head;
        if (rare < 0)
        {
            cout <<"Queue under flow";
            return;
        }
        cout<<"\nthe queue is: \n\n";
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout <<temp->name<<endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    void pop()
    {

        if( rare < 0)
        {
            cout <<"Queue under flow\n";
            return;
        }
        if(front == rare)
        {
            front = rare =-1;
            head=NULL;
            return;
        }
        front++;
        head=head->next;
    }

    Queue Delete(Queue q){
        node* temp = head;
        while (head != nullptr){
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = head;
        }
        head  = nullptr;
    }

};


main()
{
    Queue q1;
    string x;
    int ch;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"1.PUSH\n2.POP\n3.DISPLAY\n4.DELETE\n5.EXIT\nenter Ur choice:\n";
        cin >> ch;

        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:
            cout <<"plz,enter the name \n";
            cin >> x;
            q1.push(x);
            cout<<"\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            q1.pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            q1.display();
            cout<<"\n";
            break;
        case 4:
            q1.Delete(q1);
            break;
        case 5:
            exit(0);
        default :
            cout<<"error selection.plz,try again\n";
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: When debugging attempt to craft an example that exposes one error at a time and requires no input. This allows you to debug with as few distractions as possible. Use [mcve] as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that in the name "Michael," there are no spaces, but in "Emily Glassberg," there are. I believe that std::cin has a hard time handling this so you should use std::getline and change ch to a std::string (you'll have to include  for that). The code will need to look something like this to work properly:

```
ch.clear();
int chInt;
while(ch.size() == 0) {
    std::getline(std::cin, ch);
}
chInt = std::stoi(ch);
//Handle the input here
```

You need the loop because for whatever reason, std::getline tends to only try to get an input from the user once for whatever reason and then move on, so by looping until the user does input something, we can ensure that the correct input will always be taken. It is also very important that you clear the string beforehand, so that we don't automatically use the last input in any future input collectors. Lastly, the line `chInt = std::stoi(ch);` converts the string we just collected from the user, turns it into an int, and then assigns it to chInt (so in your `switch` statement, you would use chInt instead of ch). Implementing this fix may or may not help out in the second half of the problem as well.

Comment: Thanks for help, I added this line getline(cin,x); after the line cin>>x. After I run the code and choose **PUSH** then type two names like "Emily Glassberg" , and choose **DISPLAY** only the second name appears.

Answer (score 0):

1. First delete without PUSH is  not working because head pointer  not initialized, then the line: head = head->next cause error. You must initialize head to null in constructor and in Delete you must verify if head diferent that null.
2. In PUSH :

   while(temp->next != NULL) { temp=temp->next; }

   when temp=NULL then the condition temp->next crash because temp is null. Change condition by while(temp!=null) or by this: while(temp != null && temp->next!=null)
3. cin >> x. 
   when you enter "Emily Glassberg" then cin read Emily and return. Next loop cin > ch return "Glassberg" then not a valid option and loop infinite. Use cin.getline() in PUSH option rather than cin >> x.
4. In Delete you must set -1 to bare because next PUSH the head was not initialized. Also, you must delete in recursive form.

Comment: Hey  bro thanks for help, for point 3 I added this line getline(cin,x); after the line cin>>x. After I run the code and choose **PUSH** then type two names like "Emily Glassberg" , and choose **DISPLAY** only the second name appears.

Comment: delete line: cin >> x;

Comment: I deleted it and the infinite loop went back again.

Comment: replace the line: cin >> ch; by this lines:  while (true) {
   ch = _getch();
   ch = ch - '0';
   if (ch >= 1 && ch <= 5) break;
   ch = 0;
   cout << "error selection.plz,try again\n";
  }